# Reading form a file only displays the last inputted string, creates the file but it is empty

Tags: c++

My program creates a file and names it after user input, after that it will continue to loop to and ask if you want to keep adding to the file created. after you say no, then it will close the file and read the first three lines of the file created. My program does not output anything into the file, it appears empty and does read three lines but they are the last user inputted line but three times. How to fix this? Here is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//Global Variables
fstream File;
string fileName, writeToFile;
char choice;

void write();
void read();
void exitprogram();

int main()
{
    // Name and open the output file
    cout << "What is the file name that you want to create?" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    cout << "File " << fileName << " has been created!" << endl;

    ofstream File(fileName.c_str());

    File.open(fileName.c_str());

    if (File.is_open())
    {
        cout << "File opened successfully." << endl;
        write();
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

void write()
{
    choice = ' ';

    cout << "What do you want to add?: " << endl;
    getline(cin.ignore(),writeToFile);
    File << writeToFile << endl;

    cout << "Do you want to add something else to the file (1=YES or 2=NO): ";
    cin >> choice;

    switch(choice)
    {
        case '1' :
            write();
            break;
        case '2' :
            cout << "Saving..." << endl;
            File.close();
            read();
            break;
    }
}

void read()
{
    cout <<"Here are the first there lines of file " << fileName << endl;
    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 3; counter++)
    {
        File >> writeToFile;
        cout << writeToFile << endl;
    }
    exitprogram();
}

void exitprogram()
{
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `ofstream File(fileName.c_str()); File.open(fileName.c_str());` its redundant to all open on a file with the same parameter you passed to the constructor because the file should already have been opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **shadowed** the global `File` used by `write` by declaring another in `main`.  (The moral is not to use global variables—pretty much never.  Pass **parameters** instead, although most of yours can just be made local anyway.)